# High latency, packet loss and keyboard lag when typing on an OpenVPN client

Tags: openvpn, linux-networking

I have an OpenVPN server that has two clients in the subnet. When I ssh from Client 1 to Client 2, there is long lag when I type and when letter appears in terminal. SSH from OpenVPN server to Client 2, there is no lag. There is lag between OpenVPN server and Client 2 back and forth using SSH. All three nodes are running Debian, the server is configured UDP. How can I begin to troubleshoot this?

Did the ping test and the results are"

1. Ping from client 1 to client 2 via the tunnel

```
20 packets transmitted, 14 received, 30% packet loss, time 19169ms

rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 70.827/72.071/78.295/1.815 ms
```

2. Ping from client 2 to client 1 via the tunnel

```
60 packets transmitted, 55 received, 8% packet loss, time 59383ms

rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 70.730/176.441/5773.739/761.702 ms, pipe 6
```

3. Ping from OpenVPN server to client 2: Here the avg latency varies from 35 ms to 1741 ms. The results below are from second trial of ping.

```
20 packets transmitted, 20 received, 0% packet loss, time 19251ms

rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 26.454/1741.058/5625.208/1952.415 ms, pipe 6
```

4. Ping from Client 2 to OpenVPN server

```
20 packets transmitted, 20 received, 0% packet loss, time 19251ms

rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 26.454/1741.058/5625.208/1952.415 ms, pipe 6
```

5. Ping from Client 1 to OpenVPN server

```
Try 1: Significant packet loss
38 packets transmitted, 27 received, 28% packet loss, time 37260ms

rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 44.601/516.754/6025.636/1480.910 ms, pipe 6

Try 2: Not much packet loss

20 packets transmitted, 20 received, 0% packet loss, time 19022ms

rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 44.712/98.499/1077.521/224.708 ms, pipe 2
```

6. Ping from OpenVPN server to client 1

````
Try 1:

20 packets transmitted, 20 received, 0% packet loss, time 19027ms

rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 44.703/44.979/45.196/0.192 ms

Try 2:

20 packets transmitted, 20 received, 0% packet loss, time 19028ms

rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 44.759/76.936/678.993/138.122 ms```
````

Comment: Client to client communication in OpenVPN does not take place directly but still goes through the server, so both "client1 to server" and "server to client2" latencies add up. If either channel experiences packet drops, it also impedes the whole communication. From your pings I see both channels are unstable. It is no suprprise you have a latency.

Comment: Ok, but how do I troubleshoot this further aside from ping.